# More efficient active record grouping

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Im trying to check 2.5 second intervals for records and add an object to an array based on the count.  This way works but its far too slow. thanks

```
   @tweets = Tweet.last(3000)
   first_time = @tweets.first.created_at
   last_time = @tweets.last.created_at
    while first_time < last_time

      group = @tweets.where(created_at: (first_time)..(first_time + 2.5.seconds)).count
        if group == 0 || nil
            puts "0 or nil"
            first_id + 1
            array << {tweets: 0}
          else
            first_id += group
            array << {tweets: group}
        end
      first_time += 2.5.seconds
    end
       return array.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need is the `group_by` method on the records you've retrieved:

```
grouped = @tweets.group_by do |tweet|
  # Convert from timestamp to 2.5s interval number
  (tweet.created_at.to_f / 2.5).to_i
end
```

That returns a hash with the key being the time interval, and the values being an array of tweets.

What you're doing in your example probably has the effect of making thousands of queries. Always watch `log/development.log` to see what's going on in the background.

Comment: Yes. First pass, group into arrays. Second pass, iterate over that and fill in the blanks.